# How it not working add class using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

It may be click photo and not add class inside the `ng-repeat` using **AngularJS**

```
<div class="resultitem" ng-repeat="a in vm.gettrustalbum">
    <div class="result">
    </div>
</div>
```

Add class `demo` inside the `ng-repeat`

Output:

```
<div class="resultitem" ng-repeat="a in vm.gettrustalbum">
    <div class="result demo">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try reading about `ng-class`

Comment: what does your css look like?

Comment: it also already apply but not statisfied

Comment: .resultitem .result.demo {
    height: 675px;
}

Comment: share your array stub as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<div class="resultitem" ng-repeat="a in vm.gettrustalbum">
    <div class="result" ng-class="vm.classname"></div>
</div>
```

Load Class from your JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are having something `unique` in ur `array`

```
<div class="resultitem" ng-repeat="a in vm.gettrustalbum">
     <div class="result" ng-class={"demo":a.unique}>
     </div>
  </div>
```

You can do some thing like this...

Share your array i will give u final answer